# Running Scala Files in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, ide

I'm trying to run a scala file with Eclipse Indigo. I have installed the Scala IDE for Eclipse and am on the Scala perspective, but the option to run as a Scala application does not appear. The file that I am currently trying to run is part of an existing project that I imported into Eclipse. The Scala IDE plugin appears to be working as I can create Scala objects and run them as Scala Applications and the Scala compiler is detecting errors.

How do I get the option to run a file as a Scala Application for the Scala IDE plugin for Eclipse Indigo?

Comment: You need to copy-paste some code. As people have noted, it *should* work. There's nothing else you need to do, as long as the project builds without errors, and the main signature is correct (and inside an object).

Answer (score 2):

The file you are trying to run must either be defined like this:

```
object MyFile extends App { /* your code to run here */ }
```

or:

```
object MyFile {
  def main(args: Array[String]) { /* your code to run here */ }
}
```

If either of these are true, you should be able to press the play button, via right click or the toolbar at the top.

Comment: the signature of the main method must be def `main(args: Array[String])` rather than def `main(args: List[String])`

Comment: @Faiz Good catch on the block comments.

Comment: The signature of the method is defined as main(args: Array[String]) but Eclipse cannot recognize a main method for the object.